# Distribution of area of randomly placed circles

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, plane-geometry

I've searched the web now for ages to try and find a paper on the asymptotic distribution of the area of the union of randomly placed discs on the plane. Ideally, I would be looking for the discs to be placed in a unit square, but if anyone knows of other work that has been done, that would be great. I can calculate the expected area, and I have found a number of papers on the topic of 'coverage of wireless sensor networks' which give some useful ideas. Nevertheless, I was wondering whether this problem has ever been studied for its own sake.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103432/rain-droplets-falling-on-a-table and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176383/rain-droplets-falling-on-a-table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "the area of ... circles" you mean the area of the union of disks,
then there is work in the statistical literature, e.g.:

> Zikmundová, Markéta, Kateřina Staňková Helisová, and Viktor Beneš. "Spatio-temporal model for a random set given by a union of interacting discs." *Methodology and Computing in Applied Probability* 14.3 (2012): 883-894.
>
> Møller, Jesper, and Kateřina Helisová. "Likelihood inference for unions of interacting discs." *Scandinavian Journal of Statistics* 37.3 (2010): 365-381.
>
> Møller, Jesper, and Kateřina Helisová. "Power diagrams and interaction processes for unions of discs." *Advances in Applied Probability* (2008): 321-347.

[image: Fig.1]

 
 
 
 
 
Fig. 1 from 3rd paper above.

Comment: Yes i did mean the union. Thank you very much this is helpful, sometimes the problem i have is not knowing exactly what to search for.